# dpkg-deb builds invalid package

Tags: dpkg

I want to create a simple Debian package containing a Python program (`foo`).

```
$ ls -R dist/
dist/:
DEBIAN  usr

dist/DEBIAN:
control

dist/usr:
local

dist/usr/local:
bin

dist/usr/local/bin:
foo

$ cat dist/DEBIAN/control 
Package: foo
Version: 0.0.0
Architecture: amd64
Maintainer: ...
Depends: gettext, python-pip, tar
Section: admin
Priority: optional
Description: ...
```

When I use `dpkg-deb` on Debian 9 then a valid package is created:

```
$ dpkg-deb --version
Debian 'dpkg-deb' package archive backend version 1.18.24 (amd64).
...
$ dpkg-deb -b dist foo.deb
...
$ dpkg-deb -c foo.deb
drwxr-xr-x gerald/gerald     0 2017-12-28 13:51 ./
drwxr-xr-x gerald/gerald     0 2017-12-28 13:51 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x gerald/gerald     0 2017-12-28 13:51 ./usr/local/
drwxr-xr-x gerald/gerald     0 2017-12-28 13:51 ./usr/local/bin/
-rwxr-xr-x gerald/gerald  3786 2017-12-28 13:51 ./usr/local/bin/foo
```

But when I use the same command on Ubuntu 14.04 then the package can't be installed:

```
$ dpkg-deb --version
Debian `dpkg-deb' package archive backend version 1.17.5 (amd64).
...
$ dpkg-deb -b dist foo.deb
...
$ dpkg-deb -c foo.deb
drwxr-xr-x gerald/gerald     0 2017-12-28 13:51 ./
drwxr-xr-x gerald/gerald     0 2017-12-28 13:51 ./DEBIAN/
-rw-r--r-- gerald/gerald   297 2017-12-28 13:51 ./DEBIAN/control
drwxr-xr-x gerald/gerald     0 2017-12-28 13:51 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x gerald/gerald     0 2017-12-28 13:51 ./usr/local/
drwxr-xr-x gerald/gerald     0 2017-12-28 13:51 ./usr/local/bin/
-rwxr-xr-x gerald/gerald  3786 2017-12-28 13:51 ./usr/local/bin/foo
drwxr-xr-x gerald/gerald     0 2017-12-28 13:51 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x gerald/gerald     0 2017-12-28 13:51 ./usr/local/
drwxr-xr-x gerald/gerald     0 2017-12-28 13:51 ./usr/local/bin/
-rwxr-xr-x gerald/gerald  3786 2017-12-28 13:51 ./usr/local/bin/foo
drwxr-xr-x gerald/gerald     0 2017-12-28 13:51 ./usr/local/
drwxr-xr-x gerald/gerald     0 2017-12-28 13:51 ./usr/local/bin/
-rwxr-xr-x gerald/gerald  3786 2017-12-28 13:51 ./usr/local/bin/foo
drwxr-xr-x gerald/gerald     0 2017-12-28 13:51 ./usr/local/bin/
-rwxr-xr-x gerald/gerald  3786 2017-12-28 13:51 ./usr/local/bin/foo
-rwxr-xr-x gerald/gerald  3786 2017-12-28 13:51 ./usr/local/bin/foo
$ sudo dpkg -i foo.deb
(Reading database ... 430408 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack foo.deb ...
Unpacking foo ...
dpkg: error processing archive foo.deb (--install):
trying to overwrite '/DEBIAN/control', which is also in package bar
Errors were encountered while processing:
foo.deb
```

Comment: The packed can be installed, but on the Ubuntu system you have another packet, bar, that also contains /DEBIAN/control. You probably don't have that package on your debian system.

Comment: @SorenA also irrelevant, the `debian/control` files aren't supposed to be written to the system.  Which suggests that OP has a broken package to begin with.

Comment: I'd ask you to share the source package directives you're using to populate and create the package, but I'm sure you might not be able to.  BEFORE building the package, wherever you'ire running `dpkg-deb` for building the package in, can you include the `ls` of your `debian` directory, as well as any `install` files you have in that directory?  My *guess* is you're not properly giving an `install` file *which actually tells older Debian and dpkg versions how to properly install packages* in your source package.

Comment: @ThomasWard I have added a directory listing.  There is only a `control` file and no `install` files. Do you mean `dpkg` 1.17.x is  too old and requires other files than 1.18.x?

Comment: @G.Fiedler No, I'm saying your package is not compliant with the Debian rules of packages.  I hate to throw you to another link (in this case, the [Debian New Maintainer's Guide](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/)) but this is actually quite a good resource for how to 'create' compliant packages.  Namely also, your folder named `DEBIAN` should be named `debian`, and probably needs to be fleshed out to have much more of a 'robust' package setup.  Let me do more research, and get back to you *spins up test package environment*

Comment: @G.Fiedler The 'error' you get - did you build that package on your own system that is not 14.04, or did you build that within 14.04?

Comment: I built and (tried to) install this package on 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I should point out the following: `dpkg-deb` is a ***hackish*** approach to making a package.  It only follows the bare minimum and relies on your existing system libraries as build dependencies.  It in turn is not a very reliable method to **create** packages which you wish to distribute outside your specific system for that reason, among others (such as `dpkg` version and requirement incongruities because of the Debian standards required in the given system).

This is why the Ubuntu Packaging Guide recommends building packages completely within `pbuilder` and following the `dh_make` templates for brand new packages (which in fact actually pulls data from the Debian packaging guide for some bits, heh)

---

Now, I took a *very* basic packaging approach here, and [made a very simple package just containing a single script](https://github.com/teward/dpkg-deb-tests).

You'll note I have a bit more in my `DEBIAN/` directory.  Most of the files here are stock files created with `dh_make` as if I were starting to follow the packaging guide for creating a package.  However, I just renamed `debian/` that it creates to `DEBIAN/`, kept the `install` file but specifically told it what I needed it to do with installing, kept the `postinst` file because I'm too lazy to `chmod +x` the script before installing (so the `postinst` script will set it as executable), etc.  You can look at the specific details in your own time.

Now, with the above package 'structure', in a 14.04 LXD container (because I run 16.04 everywhere, so LXD images help me have older versions for testing things), I ran `dpkg-deb` and had some niceness happen:

```
root@trusty-deb-tests:~/temptests# dpkg-deb -b testingdata-0.0.1/
dpkg-deb: warning: 'testingdata-0.0.1//DEBIAN/control' contains user-defined field 'Build-Depends'
dpkg-deb: warning: 'testingdata-0.0.1//DEBIAN/control' contains user-defined field 'Standards-Version'
dpkg-deb: warning: ignoring 2 warnings about the control file(s)

dpkg-deb: building package `testingdata' in `testingdata-0.0.1.deb'.
root@trusty-deb-tests:~/temptests# ls
testingdata-0.0.1  testingdata-0.0.1.deb
root@trusty-deb-tests:~/temptests# dpkg-deb -c testingdata-0.0.1.deb
drwxrwxr-x root/root         0 2017-12-28 15:09 ./
drwxrwxr-x root/root         0 2017-12-28 15:09 ./dist/
-rw-r--r-- root/root        15 2017-12-28 15:09 ./dist/hellothere.sh
root@trusty-deb-tests:~/temptests#
```

So firstly, I believe *something* is odd in your package.  Even if I remove everything but the control file on my side, it *still* works properly, though it doesn't know how to write files, and doesn't recognize how to write to the proper location with my 'test'.

Something specific to your package is busted.  I'd suggest you 'start' with the baseline I have in that GitHub repository I linked, and work your way from there.  (Having the `install` file inside the `DEBIAN` folder also is good practice so you know what's installing where).